# Why does in_array() always return false?

Tags: php, arrays, session, boolean

Try this code:

You use the URL with the parameter `id` e.g `index.php?id=value`
This *value* will be pushed into the `data` array that is maintained within a session.

I expect this test to always return `true`. But it always returns `false`, why?

```
   if (in_array($id, $_SESSION['data'])) {
        echo "$id in array";
    } else {
        echo "$id not in array";
    }
```

The full code:

```
<?php

    session_start();

     //uncomment when need to clear the data array.
    //if (isset($_SESSION['data'])) {
    //    unset($_SESSION['data']);
    //    die;
    //}

    if (!isset($_SESSION['data'])) {
        $_SESSION['data'] = [];
    }
    if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
        $id = strval($_GET['id']);

        if (!in_array($id, $_SESSION['data'])) {
            $_SESSION['data'][$id] = "data_$id";
        }

        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($_SESSION['data']);
        echo '</pre>';

        // Why does this always return false?
        if (in_array($id, $_SESSION['data'])) {
            echo "$id in array";
        } else {
            echo "$id not in array";
        }
    }?>
```

Comment: `in_array` checks values, not keys.

Comment: @JonStirling Opps.. then I need to use `array_key_exists` instead - Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try **isset()** function.

**Example:-**

```
if (isset($_SESSION['data'][$id])) {
  echo "$id in array";
} else {
  echo "$id not in array";
}
```